# How to place icons around CircleAvatar

Tags: flutter, icons, frontend

I'm developing a mobile app with Flutter and I'd like to place some tiny icons around a CircleAvatar. See the red points below:

[image: what I want to do]

In the following there is the code that handle it:

```
  Widget _createHeader(BuildContext context) {
return UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
  accountEmail: Text(userEmail),
  accountName: Text(userName),
  currentAccountPicture: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(110),
    child:
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userImageUrl),
          radius: 60,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
    ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
        ),
);
```

}

I'd like to icons to follow the roundness of the circle but I have no ideas how to achieve it.
I have tried to wrap the `CircleAvatar` into a `Row` or a `Container` but I did not manage to obtain the effect. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if you can wrap it directly around the widget but you can use combination of `Stack` and `Positioned` to achieve this. You need to customize `radius`, `iconSize` and `distance` variables in this example as per your requirement.
[image]

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double radius = 40;
    double iconSize = 20;
    double distance = 10;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:
        Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: radius,
                backgroundImage:
                    NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              Positioned(
                  top: -(radius + iconSize + distance),
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: radius,
                  left: 0,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.access_alarm,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: iconSize,
                  )),
              Positioned(
                  top: -(iconSize + radius),
                  right: -(radius + iconSize - distance),
                  bottom: iconSize,
                  left: radius,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.email,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: iconSize,
                  )),
              Positioned(
                  top: -(radius - distance),
                  right: -(radius + iconSize + distance),
                  bottom: -iconSize,
                  left: radius,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.account_balance,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: iconSize,
                  )),
            ]),
      ),
    );
}
```